# PHP Header Location: ../location vs $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]/location

Tags: php, redirect, header, location

So, I made a simple PHP login, but when I tried to redirect like this:

```
$path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];  
header("Location: $path/admin/index.php");
```

it seemed like it did nothing, but after I refreshed the page I was logged in.
After I changed my code to this:

```
header("Location: ../admin/index.php");
```

it works.

Could someone please explain this to me?

Ps. sorry for my bad english

Comment: echo `$path/admin/index.php` and see the value

Comment: With @sidyll 's comment it makes sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The header is sent to the browser, so it is not an internal server maneuver. And with it not being an internal redirect, you don't deal with internal paths. When you use `DOCUMENT_ROOT` you will get the internal server path to the directory where your files are located.

If you want to reference the root of the site as a URL, just use `/`.

```
header("Location: /admin/index.php");
header("Location: /"); # go to homepage, for example
```

Your `..` worked because you probably were on a subdirectory, and `..` was translated to the parent directory which is where `admin` is.

Answer (score 1):

```
$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
```

returns path like `/var/www/html/yourfolder/`, but you have to redirect to `website.com/yourfolder/` or `localhost/yourfolder/`.

hence that won't work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried printing the value of $path?

the value of $path is relative to the actual file location

e.g. `$path = '/c/inetpub/sites/example/main/'`

You probably wanted something like `'/c/inetpub/sites/example/'` or `'/c/inetpub/sites/example/main/..'`

Comment: "_the value of $path is relative to the actual file location_" no, `$path` is his document root which is fixed. Not relative to anything.