# PHP | 404 Object not Found

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

i have a problem with my website. it should get a Login/Sign Up website. If i type in my First and Last name, password and so, i click on submit and 404 Object not Found Appears. The Files are in the correct directory... btw, im not using a htaccess file yet so u dont need to ask for it.

sry for my basic english :)

`

```
if (isset($POST_['submit'])) 
include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

$first = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['first']);
$last = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['last']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['email']);
$uid = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['uid']);
$pwd = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['pwd']);

//error handler
//Check for empty fields
if (empty($first) || empty($last) || empty($email) || empty($uid) || empty($pwd)) {
    header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=empty")
    exit();
} else {
    //Check if inputs are valid
    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) || !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/", $first) ) {
        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=invalid")
        exit();
    } else {
        //check if email is valid
        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=email")
            exit();
        } else {
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id='$uid'";
            $result =  mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
            $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($results);

            if ($resultCheck > 0) {
                header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=usernametaken")
                exit();
        } else { 
            //hashing passwords
            $hashedPwd = password_hash($pwd, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
            //Insert the user into DB
            $sql = "INSER INTO users (user_first, user_last, user_email, user_uid, user_pwd) VALUES ('$first', '$
            last', '$email', '$uid', '$hashedPwd');";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        header("Location: ../signup.php?signup=succes")
                exit();
        }
    }   
}



} else {
header("Location: ../signup.php")
exit();
}`
```

Comment: Does this code actually even execute? It looks like you have a syntax error as you forgot to add `{` on `if (isset($POST_['submit']))`..

Comment: Page not found error means `The Files are in the correct directory.` this may not be correct.

Comment: Everything is at the right place. http://prntscr.com/jp0pr7

Comment: Should i maybe reinstall Xampp

Comment: Did Mr Glass's solution provide you with the solution or are you still having the issue? Best way to confirm if you are being directed to the correct place is by looking at the URL. Do not reinstall Xampp

Comment: By the way; it's `$_POST` not `$POST_`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know you can't use '..' notation in header('location:'). Browsers don't understand '..' notation.

You should use either a fully qualified URL or a relative URL:

- header('Location: http://example.com/your-subdirectories/signup.php') ;
- header('Location: /your-subdirectories/signup.php') ;

[This question has already been answered on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41379727/php-header-location-location-vs-serverdocument-root-location)

Comment: @vinix, can you please post the the full 404 error you are receiving? We may be able to learn something from the URL or path displayed in the error.